# How to setup WildFly 10.1.0.Final as Linux service?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, redhat

I want to setup WildFly 10.1.0.Final as a Linux service. However all guides on the net are for versions of WildFly prior to 10.1.0.Final and make reference to an init.d directory inside the /wildfly/bin/ directory.

On 10.1.0.Final there does not exist such a directory to cope the init script from.

I need to run 10.1.0.Final on CentOS 7. Any advice or pointers to a guide will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts do in fact exist in your WildFly 10.1.0.Final distribution - they have simply been moved.

Have a look in `$JBOSS_HOME/docs/contrib/scripts`.

Comment: Thanks, most appreciated.